# How to get app rating of an app on the play store?

Tags: java, android, google-play

How can i get the app rating (stars) of an application published on the play store?

Something like

```
public int getCurrentAverageAppRating(String packageName)
```

that will return for example 3,50 (three and a half stars)

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/AndlyticsProject/andlytics

Answer (score 0):

There is no offical API I know of. I can only suggest using unoffical one: https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/ But I don't know how reliable it is or does it even work.